# Using format specifiers on Linux system call write()

Tags: linux, format, system, specifier

I am trying to write to stdout using only Linux system calls described in section 2 of the manual (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html).

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

is the function I am trying to use, however the I am trying to incorporate format specifiers into the buffer. Ideally it would work like so:

```
char *adjective = argv[1];
write(1, "This is a %s example\n", adjective, 19 + strlen(adjective));
```

But I obviously cannot do this. How would I go about getting something similar done?

Also, I know strlen() isn't a part of section 2 of the Linux system calls. I'm including it for simplicity since counting the length of the buffer isn't part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf()` to format into a buffer, which you then write:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
int size = snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZE, "This is a %s example\n", adjective);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

If you can't use `sprintf()`, just write each string separately.

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is a ", sizeof "This is a ");
write(STDOUT_FILENO, adjective, strlen(adjective));
write(STDOUT_FILENO, " example", sizeof " example");
```

Comment: Unfortunately for this assignment, I cannot use snprintf() as it is not in section 2 of the Linux manual.

Comment: Then you can't use format specifiers, they're part of the `printf()` family of functions.

Comment: Gotcha! I was starting to suspect I couldn't do it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have to use format specifiers? If you do, it sounds like you're supposed to implement your own version of `printf()`.

Comment: An example string includes use of format specifiers, (""The elapsed time to execute %d copies of \"%s\" on %d processors is %7.3fsec\n") and the non-function requirements state that I can only use Linux system calls from section 2 of the manual.

Comment: Then I guess you're supposed to write your own implementation of `printf()`. And if you can only use section 2 functions, that also means you will have to write your own code that  converts integers and floating points to text. In other words, you've been tasked to reimplement a huge amount of the standard C library.

Comment: I hope you don't have a short deadline, you're talking about weeks of work for an experienced programmer.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I just finished. Unfortunately, I missed the deadline by about 11 months but it was worth the journey!